# how to add camera taken image to existing image

Tags: android, image-processing

i am android beginner developer . i want to to get some hints about my problem.
problem : how to add image on certain point of existing image android. There are lot of apps waterfall effect . They take picture from camera and append picture on existing waterfall image .

please refer me any good lib or procedure

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);



     @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String selectedImagePath = getRealPathFromURIForGallery(selectedImageUri);
                decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
    }

     public String getRealPathFromURIForGallery(Uri uri) {
            if (uri == null) {
                return null;
            }
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                int column_index = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
            return uri.getPath();
        }

     public void decodeFile(String filePath) {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;
            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);


            profileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
```

Comment: this code just pic image and show in image view not embed one picture on other right ?